# How do I print the reading serial data sending from Arduino

Tags: serial, programming, c++

I am sending data to Arduino using QtSerialPort. When I read the data the ouput has several not printer characters. I am using a QTexEdit (in left hand) to insert the data to send and other (in right hand) to insert  the data to read.

[image]

You can see the receive data has some no printer character.

## Workflow of sending and receiving data between QtSerialPort and Arduino

#### Sending Data with QtSerialPort

```
void MainWindow::sendData(){

    QString m_allData = m_sendEdit->toPlainText();
    int i = 0;
    int size = m_allData.size();

    QString line = "";
    int c = 0;
    while(i < size){
        line.append(m_allData[i]);
        if(c == 24){
            int sended = m_serialPort->write(line.toUtf8(), 24);
            m_serialPort->flush();
            line.clear();
            c = 0;
        }
        i++;
        c++;
    }
    if(c > 0){
        m_serialPort->write(line.toUtf8(), c);
    }
    m_serialPort->flush();
}
```

I want to send the data with a buffer size of 24 bytes.

#### Reading and Sending Data with Arduino

```
 void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
 }

 void loop() {

    delay(1000);

    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        short i = 0;
        int size = Serial.available();
        String data = Serial.readString();
        Serial.print(data);
    }
 }
```

The Arduino code is simple.

#### Receiving Data with QtSerialPort

```
void MainWindow::readData(){
    int c = 0;
    char * dataBuffer;
    int size = m_serialPort->bytesAvailable();
    dataBuffer = new char[size];
    c = m_serialPort->read(dataBuffer, size);
    m_receiveEdit->setText(m_receiveEdit->toPlainText() + QString::fromUtf8(dataBuffer));
        delete dataBuffer;
}
```

I am trying to read the same data that I send to Arduino. What kind of convertion do I have to do?

Comment: There is no point in splitting your writes into 12-byte chunks. The serial port is slow, and your Qt code is fast, thus the first byte of the second chunk will come right after the last byte of the first chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no warranty that Qt will receive the whole message in a single
chunk. It may receive "no se" as the first chunk, and then "q pasa" as
the second chunk. Since `dataBuffer` is dynamically allocated, it
initially contains garbage, and you are printing the part of this
garbage that you did not overwrite.

An easy fix would be to simply NULL-terminate the buffer:

```c++
dataBuffer = new char[size + 1];            // + 1 byte for '\0'
c = m_serialPort->read(dataBuffer, size);
dataBuffer[c] = '\0';                       // terminate the string
```

Comment: Ok, that was the problem. with `dataBuffer['c'] = '\0'` the output data is clean. Thank you @Edgar Bonet